# Changing column width of a protected sheet - apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a use case where use should be able to adjust the column width in a protected Excel sheet generated using apache poi. I tried [lockFormatColumns](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#lockFormatColumns-boolean-) but it did not worked. Is it possible to allow column resize even if the sheet is protected ?
I also tried out the answer given in [apache-poi-lock-the-cell-but-allow-column-resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48787000/apache-poi-lock-the-cell-but-allow-column-resize) but did not worked as expected.

PS: The above actually worked, the issue was I'm using linux and using Libre office, some how it did not work for Libre office but worked fine in Microsoft Office.

Comment: For me this works. The sheet is protected but formatting columns, including column width, is possible. What Excel version are you using?

Comment: @AxelRichter I'm using Apache poi version: 5.1.0

Comment: Me too. But using what **Excel** version does it not work?

Comment: Oh @AxelRichter I'm actually in linux I'm using Libre Office 7.1.7.2

Comment: @AxelRichter Seems like it's the case, I tried on Excel online from onedrive it worked !!!  Thank you very much, seems like libre office dosen't support this somehow

Comment: LibreOffice is not able to allow column formatting when sheet is protected. It only can allow to: Select protected cells, Select unprotected cells, Insert columns, Insert rows, Delete columns and Delete rows. See https://help.libreoffice.org/7.3/en-US/text/scalc/01/06060100.html.